# How does jboss-as maven plugin handle password

Tags: maven-plugin, jboss-eap-6

I got an issue with our IT support regarding the handling of the management api password in the maven plugin for jboss (jboss-as-maven-plugin, latest version). 
Is the password encrypted by the jboss-as plugin or is it sent in clear text over the net to the api?

Couldn't find anything in the documentation.